# Java : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at javaapplication9.Tictactoe.setPlay

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an error index out of bound when input > 2

Here is my code

```
private String[][] board;
private static final int ROWS = 3;
private static final int COLUMNS = 3;
private String regex = "\\s{3}";

    public void initializeBoard() {
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
            board[i][j] = "   ";
        }
    }
}

public boolean setPlay(int i, int j, String player) {
    if(board[i][j].matches(regex)) {
        board[i][j] = " "+player+" ";
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("The cell is already taken.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have good solution for my code?

Comment: It would be great and useful if you share the stack trace and datatype of "board" variable. With this small information, we're are unable to help you.

Comment: Well, your board most likely has a size of 3x3 (it's Tictactoe after all) so any index > 2 will be invalid. You might want to refresh your knowledge on arrays (for an array of length 3 valid indices would be 0, 1 and 2).

Comment: `private String[][] board;
 private static final int ROWS = 3;
 private static final int COLUMNS = 3;
 private String regex = "\\s{3}";`

there is my variable

Comment: someting that i want is, when user input >2 will going to this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of an array starts from 0 and ends with (length -1). In your case the index range is 0 - 2 (0, 1, 2). You are trying to call the method with index 3 which throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. Try checking the index range before executing the logic in your method.

For E.g.

```
public boolean setPlay(int i, int j, String player) {
    if (i < 0 || i > 2 || j < 0 || j > 2) {
        System.out.println("Invalid cell. Try again.");
        return false;
    } else {
        if (board[i][j].matches(regex)) {
            board[i][j] = " " + player + " ";
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("The cell is already taken.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want your cell to start from 1 and end with 3 you can substract 1 from the i and j in the method before accessing/mutating the array.

For E.g.

```
public boolean setPlay(int i, int j, String player) {
    if (i < 1 || i > 3 || j < 1 || j > 3) {
        System.out.println("Invalid cell. Try again.");
        return false;
    } else {
        if (board[i - 1][j - 1].matches(regex)) {
            board[i - 1][j - 1] = " " + player + " ";
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("The cell is already taken.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting error, i want to validate user input using only 0-2

Comment: What error you are getting now?

Answer (score 1):

In your `setPlay` method, you are passing input values of `i` or `j` with an integer value larger than 2. You should only allow input values from 0 to 2.